# How to rename a specific file into folder's name for many folders

Tags: bash

I have many directories as out_00, out_01, out_02 ,.... Each directory includes a specific file as "results.fits" (same name but different content). I want to create a new directory as "results" and save all "results.fits" with new name as "results_00.fits", "results_01.fits", "results_02.fits"  and finally save all fits files as a csv file, all_results.csv. Could you please help me?

Comment: Do these directory share a common parent directory? Like `out_00, out_01, out_02, ...`, are they in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

mkdir results

ls | grep 'out_[0-9][0-9]' |
    while read dir
    do
        [ -d "$dir" ] && mv "$dir"/results.fits results/"results_${dir##*_}.fits"
    done

cat results/* > all_results.csv
```

This would do it if all those directories are in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask one more question? below code converts .txt file into .csv, can I add this code to the above script . (assuming I saved txt format instead of fits format)?  
 sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/;/g' results_00.txt > results_00.csv

Comment: @Negar, just replace all “.fits” in the code to “.txt"

Comment: @Negar, you should instead update your question. Also i was curious, if the answer is correct, why downvote?

Comment: I know it, I mean converting from txt into csv.

Comment: oh, sorry, I don't know why it happened! I try to edit my vote :(

Comment: @Negar, `sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/;/g' results_00.txt > results_00.csv` this should work correctly. I donno the contents of te file so can’t tell the exact result.

Comment: @Mihir @ melpomene Thank you.

Comment: @melpomene, after `ls` i am using `grep` to get the specified files and as per the question they don’t contain any special characters. I tried the same on my `mac` and I am accustomed to mac. Can you explain me what can go wrong with the same code on other unix machines?

Comment: Don't Macs support newlines in filenames?

Comment: @melpomene, they do. But it will simply display a `?` if there is a newline. My question is that when i am piping it through `grep` and looking for a specific pattern `'out_[0-9][0-9]’`, can it still cause problems?

Comment: That pattern is not very specific; it matches any filename that contains "out_" followed by two digits anywhere. Your `while read` loop mangles leading/trailing spaces as well as backslashes in filenames. The problem is not the files you want to process (`out_00/results.fits`, etc.), but other files that should not be processed but may still match.